# Vue and Tensorflow: Save classifier examples to localstorage

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, vue.js

I'm using **@tensorflow-models/knn-classifier** to classify my models and **@tensorflow-models/mobilenet** to study new models.

```
methods: {
    async init() {
      // load the load mobilenet and create a KnnClassifier
      this.classifier = knnClassifier.create();
      this.mobilenet = await mobilenetModule.load();
    },
    async addExample() {
      let selected = document.getElementById("options");
      this.class = selected.options[selected.selectedIndex].value;

      const img = tf.browser.fromPixels(this.$children[0].webcam.webcamElement);
      const logits = this.mobilenet.infer(img, "conv_preds");

      this.classifier.addExample(logits, parseInt(this.class));
    }
```

How can I save to localStorage my examples, which I added to the classifier and then load them in `init()` method? Because currently, I'm losing all my models after the page refresh.

Sorry maybe for the wrong terminology, I'm so new in Tensorflow js.

Comment: Have you tried `localStorage.setItem()`?

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov I thought there should be some methods in knn-classifier to save the whole model and then properly load.

Comment: Maybe there is, I don't know. But you can do the same thing with native `localStorage` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after small research I managed to save and load data with the next methods:

```
    async toDatasetObject(dataset) {
      const result = await Promise.all(
        Object.entries(dataset).map(async ([classId, value]) => {
          const data = await value.data();

          return {
            label: Number(classId),
            data: Array.from(data),
            shape: value.shape
          };
        })
      );

      return result;
    },
    fromDatasetObject(datasetObject) {
      return Object.entries(datasetObject).reduce(
        (result, [indexString, { data, shape }]) => {
          const tensor = tf.tensor2d(data, shape);
          const index = Number(indexString);

          result[index] = tensor;

          return result;
        },
        {}
      );
    },
```

And then I just load it:

```
this.classifier.setClassifierDataset(
   this.fromDatasetObject(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("my-data")))
);
```